# What is the significance of combining "Gangnam" with "Style"?

Tags: writing-style

How can a district be combined with "Style"? Does this show a significance in the district's style?

Comment: This is not, strictly, English: "a **Korean neologism** that refers to a lifestyle associated with the Gangnam District of Seoul" (Wikipedia). But it's an ordinary English construction, as we might speak of a "West Coast style" or a "Southern way of live" or a "New York state of mind".

Comment: "*noun* style" is an informal, intentionally silly way to say "Do something the same way that noun would". If I work "slacker style", I might not do very much work or try to get out of responsibility.

Comment: The OP has no trouble using "district's style" but is troubled by using "Gangnam style". I think the question is unclear and we need more information on specifically what the OP is confused about.

Comment: Manhattan clam chowder?

Answer (score 11):

[From Today I found out](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/12/what-does-gangnam-style-mean/)

“Gangnam” is an area in South Korea, specifically a small area in Seoul, South Korea, home to about 1% of the population of Seoul and is about the size of Manhattan.  It is known for its wealthy “new money” inhabitants.

“Gangnam Style” simply is referencing this sort of elite, “new money”, wealthy culture and lifestyle that has sprung up around the region.  Pop critic Kim Zakka, who lives in Seoul, said “Gangnam inspires both envy and distaste.  Gangnam residents are South Korea’s upper class, but South Koreans consider them self-interested, with no sense of nobility.”